# Jenkins Pipeline - git creds seemingly not being used in subsequent git operations

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing a problem where some previously set git credentials dont seem to be being used in subsequent git operations.

As per the output below, I can see the `using GIT_ASKPASS...` log showing some stored credentials in our Jenkins instance are being used to perform the initial fetch.

However, in an `Init-Common` stage of our pipeline, we need to fetch tags from the repo, and as can be seen in the final lines of the build output, this command fails with `could not read Username for 'https://github.com'`

```js
Running on EC2 (ec2-slave-magma) - Jerkins Worker V3 (i-069edcd60fee118f6) in /home/jenkins/workspace/magma-console_github_integration
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential al-cibot
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://github.com/alertlogic/al-magma-console.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/magma-console_github_integration # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/alertlogic/al-magma-console.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials CIBOT Creds for github.com AL Org
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress -- https://github.com/alertlogic/al-magma-console.git +refs/heads/integration:refs/remotes/origin/integration # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/alertlogic/al-magma-console.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/integration:refs/remotes/origin/integration # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
Checking out Revision e0b7097a57d7f2bfabf9cf5d0e77a47236b31e0c (integration)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e0b7097a57d7f2bfabf9cf5d0e77a47236b31e0c # timeout=10
Commit message: "use new merge queue jenkins pipeline branch"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 1 hr 0 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Init-Common)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ node scripts/ddInit.js
[Pipeline] echo
canceling previous builds al-magma-console github/integration 1 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob@1ee2400f[al-magma-console github/integration]
[Pipeline] sh
+ git fetch --tags --quiet
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I am confused why this would be the case, as I mention earlier our github creds do seem to be in use for that initial fetch from the repo.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you re-specify your credentials with `withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-git-creds', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD')]) {
    sh 'git fetch --tags --quiet'
}` ?

Comment: How could I get the credentialsId that was used with the `checkout scm` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the logs that the pipeline is successfully fetched from https://github.com/alertlogic/al-magma-console.git at the start using your configured credentials. However, the credentials are not exposed by default after that, within stages, for security reasons. You must surround the `sh` fetch `step` with a `withCredentials` statement to expose them at that time.

Here's an example `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage("Fetch") {
    steps {
        withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'al-cibot', gitToolName: 'git-tool')]) ) {
            sh '''
                git fetch --tags --quiet
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

Your credentials ID is `al-cibot` from the log. You can manage in the Jenkins UI settings under the credentials section.

More on the Credentials plugin: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/